# elasticsearch RemoteTransportException on dedicated server

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch

i am trying to integrate elasticsearch with production but getting the following exception.
jvm i am using in both server 1.7.0_40

> 2015-01-12 21:29:06 DEBUG netty:94 - [Whitemane, Aelfyre] connected to
>   node [[#transport#-1][inet[/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9300]]] 2015-01-12 21:29:06
>   WARN netty:114 - [Whitemane, Aelfyre] Message not fully read
>   (response) for [63] handler
>   future(org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler$1@4e70a141),
>   error [true], resetting 2015-01-12 21:29:06 INFO transport:109 -
>   [Whitemane, Aelfyre] failed to get node info for
>   [#transport#-1][inet[/xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:9300]], disconnecting...
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: Failed to
>   deserialize exception response from stream Caused by:
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to
>   deserialize exception response from stream    at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:171)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   java.io.InvalidClassException: failed to read class descriptor    at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1769)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:169)
>     ... 23 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.loadClass(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:93)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.common.io.ThrowableObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ThrowableObjectInputStream.java:67)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1599)
>     ... 34 more

Comment: Would you mind providing more details about this scenario? A simple stack trace with a sentence without details isn't quite a good post for stackoverflow. "integrate elasticsearch with production" what do you mean by that? What ES version is this?

Comment: i have server A with all the services and elasticsearch and now i want to separate elasticsearch into another server B. i have jdk 1.7.0_40 on both server, elasticsearch 0.20.5 is installed on server A and elasticseacrh 1.4.2 on server B. and now when i try to call index create service on A from server B in shows me above Exception on server A.

Comment: See my answer below. You have different versions of Elasticsearch, even more you have a huge difference in versions. And this is most likely why you get that exception.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the root exception `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException` and whatever you integrate Elasticsearch with (*integrate elasticsearch with production*) I am guessing that either:

- you are missing `elasticsearch.jar` from the classpath of your "production" system or you assume it's in classpath but, in fact, it isn't
- you are using different Elasticsearch versions (the server has one version, your "production" system uses an ES jar from another version

In Elasticsearch 0.20.5 this is the class in question: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/v0.20.5/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchException.java. Notice the name of the class - `ElasticSearchException` (capital letter "S").

In Elasticsearch 1.4.2 the class name is changed: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/v1.4.2/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchException.java. Notice the name of the class - `ElasticsearchException` (lower case "s").

So, you really need to use the same Elasticsearch version on both your servers.